# retrofit2 rxjava 2 - how can access to body of response when have error

Tags: android, android-studio, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I use Retrofit with Rxjava together for request to server.
the my server return defined json format that Include data , and defined message.
server return http response. it's ok if server return success code(200).
 but I want, if server return other code, i manage the body of that response.
for example:
the server return 401, and I want read body of response for show message of the server.
but when server other code, retrofit call the onError method and I can't use body of response.
how can solve this problem?
this is my mehod

'''

```
private void login(String username , String password){
    view.setLoading();
    source.loginUser(username, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<LoginResult>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    disposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Response<LoginResult> loginResult) {

                    if (loginResult.isSuccessful()){


                        }
                        else
         new AlertConfiguration(view.getViewActivity()).showMessage(loginResult.body().getMessage());

                    }



                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

           if there is a problem          
                }
            });
```

'''
and this is my interface method for retrofit

```
@POST("...")
Single<Response<LoginResult>> loginUser(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

Comment: Can you share the response in both cases(success, failed)? I think the API return different json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution
in retrofit onSuccess methode when response code is 200, you should get response from body object.
but when isn't 200, you should get response from errorBody;

new Gson().fromJson(serverResultResponse.errorBody().string(), ServerResult.class);

Answer (score 5):

According to info [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218), since you are already using `Response<LoginResult>` you should be able to cast the Throwable to a HttpException, and then extract the body of the response.

In Kotlin:

```
if (e is HttpException) {
    val errorBody = (e as HttpException).response().errorBody()
}
```

In Java:

```
 if (e instanceof HttpException) {
     HttpException error = (HttpException)e;
     String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().string();
 }
```

Complete example using your Java code:

```
import retrofit2.HttpException

private void login(String username , String password){
    view.setLoading();
    source.loginUser(username, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<LoginResult>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    disposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Response<LoginResult> loginResult) {
                    if (loginResult.isSuccessful()){
                      // Handle success

                    } else {
                      // Handle login failure
                       new AlertConfiguration(view.getViewActivity()).showMessage(loginResult.body().getMessage());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                  // Get the error response:
                  if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                    HttpException error = (HttpException)e;
                    String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().string();
                    // Then parse the errorBody and extract the values you need
                  }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Since the `onError` can also be caused by other exceptions inside of the call, I would avoid a forced cast and first check by `if (e instanceof HttpException)` and then cast it

Comment: Have all along been camping sites looking for this